# Angular 4 new project creation error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've recently started learning Angular 4. I have installed node and angular-cli on my machine. The problem is while I am doing an ng new and here I get the following error:

```
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.

npm ERR! path D:\UdemyDemos\my-first-app\node_modules\yeast
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\UdemyDemos\my-first-app\node_modules\yeast' -> 'D:\UdemyDemos\my-first-app\node_modules\.yeast.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-07T16_18_07_436Z-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some angular installation error. I have to follow the following steps to solve it.

npm rebuild
npm install
then ng serve app  compiled without any error